# Ending an if statement with 'else-if' is is easier to debug than 'else'?

Tags: debugging, if-statement

i.e.
User is given 2 options on display and enters an input to set the value for `intOption`.

The developer intends for the user to only select one of those 2 options.

Coding styles:

```
if(intOption == 1)
{
   do something with intOption...
}
else if(intOption == 2)
{
   do something with intOption...
}
```

vs

```
if(intOption == 1)
{
   do something with intOption...
}
else
{
   do something with intOption...
}
```

If an error occurs in the code, with the first coding style, you only have 2 cases to check: when intOption is 1 and intOption is 2.

With the second coding style, not only do you have to check when intOption is 1 and intOption is 2, you also have to check if the entered intOption is 3, 4, a, b, etc.

In this case, else-if bounds the 2nd if-segment to a tighter conditional to mean "if intOption is 2" rather than "if intOption is not 1". So for else-statements with only a limited amount of intended conditions, we should replace it with else-if and state the conditions explicitly for easier debugging?

Comment: Error handling is a complicated part of your interface.  If you silently do nothing on unexpected input, it's usually harder to debug.

Comment: If the possible values for `intOption` are only 1 and 2, you should check for those values explicitly, and handle other cases as an error.

Comment: Say you're a code reviewer, if an error occurred at an else-statement, you have refer back to all the if and else-if statements beforehand to determine what the else conditional actually is. On the other hand, if the coder just ends all his if-statements with else-ifs (if possible), then that hassle is resolved.